# ¿Como mostrar cada una de las potencias calculadas?

Tags: java

**Codifique un programa que eleve el numero x a la potencia Y. Mostrando cada una de las potencias calculadas.
El error que tengo es que no me muestra cada una las potencias calculadas.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class t22 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: ");
        int num = leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la potencia: ");
        int pot = leer.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pot; i++) {
             System.out.println((int)(Math.pow(num, pot)));

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en cada iteración estas hallando

> pow(num,pot)

entonces te mostrara n veces la misma potencia, lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar por

> pow(num,i)

Aqui lo que hallaras es la potencia del número desde el 1 hasta pot